# getting css transition value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this CSS

```
#main .timer img.hand {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: rotate(90deg); -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); -o-transform: rotate(90deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transition: transform 1.25s ease-out 0s; -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.25s ease-out 0s; -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1.25s ease-out 0s; -o-transition: -o-transform 1.25s ease-out 0s;
    transform-origin: 50% 98% 0; -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 98% 0; -moz-transform-origin: 50% 98% 0; -o-transform-origin: 50% 98% 0; -ms-transform-origin: 50% 98% 0;
}
```

and I am trying to extract the transition value in JS.

```
var $timer = $('<img>', {'class': 'hand', 'src': 'images/timer-hand.png'});

console.log($timer.css('transition')) // returns an empty string
```

I've tried '-moz-transition' as well - same result.

```
$timer.css({'transition': 'none'}); // works fine
```

Thank you

Comment: Add the image to the dom as a descendant of `#main .timer` then try it.

Comment: You should upgrade to jQuery 1.9. They'll normalize the vendor prefixes for you.

Comment: The image is on the page, I did not post the entire code - just how $timer was generated

Answer (score 0):

The transition - a shorthand property for setting the four transition properties into a single property.

transition-property 
transition-duration
transition-timing-function 
transition-delay

Set one of property:

```
console.log($timer.css('transition-property'));
console.log($timer.css('transition-delay'));
```